# SQL Select between?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a booking system for holidays for a friend.

When he enters a holiday I need to check if the dates are already in use, if they are then obviously it cannot create the booking.

I'm currently using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj 
WHERE `from` BETWEEN '2013-01-16' AND '2013-01-23'

SELECT * 
FROM anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj 
WHERE `to` BETWEEN '2013-01-16' AND '2013-01-23'
```

to see if I can book a holiday from 2013-01-16 until 2013-01-23.

in the database there is already a booking taken for 2013-01-15 until 2013-01-22 which means that the dates I am trying to book are already taken; however the sql returns 0 rows unless I use the exactly the same dates as what are already in use.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

As a note, people leave at 10am and the next people arrive at 2pm.

So if two consecutive weeks are booked it would look like

```
2013-01-14 -> 2013-01-21 
2013-01-21 -> 2013-01-28
```

Comment: What are your dates stored as?

Comment: The dates are stored like this:2013-01-14

Comment: Are you storing dates as a range or as each day having a separate entry? E.G. for 1-16 to 1-23, is that 1 entry in the db or 8 entries?

Comment: the problem is if you look at his `to`Query his dates are in the wrong order...

Comment: Updated my question, fixed initial problem. Please check my edit

Comment: For overlapping days, ie, people booked until `2013-01-28 10:00:00` and new people coming in at `2013-01-28 14:00:00`, use full DATETIME and 24 hour clock. Now you can have bookings end and start on the same day.

Answer (score 5):

You can't reverse the dates like you've done on the second query. Change it to

```
SELECT * 
FROM anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj 
WHERE `to` BETWEEN '2013-01-16' AND '2013-01-23'
```

On a side note: is your table name really `anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj`?!

Comment: This fixes my initial problem, however it causes another one as explained in my edit

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the new problem. Could you add more details?

Comment: The new problem is quite simple really. The rooms that will be booked out are vacated on the last day of the holiday, cleaned and then the next group goes in(on the same day). This is currently impossible with the SQL you gave me as the LAST DAY of the first week conflicts withe the FIRST DAY of the second week. I hope this helps

Comment: @Ryuk Okay, I got confused because I though your `16-23` range still applied to the second scenario. So you can't use BETWEEN, you'll need something like `WHERE \`to\` > '2013-01-21' AND \`to\` <= '2013-01-28'`.

Answer (score 1):

To get two dates if they are conflicting with any dates, i use a query like this. This query will return which dates are conflicting. If no rows are returned, that means that the particular time slot is free. @start_time and @end_time are parameters for the dates you want to book

```
select * from anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj 
where((@end_time > `from` and @end_time <= `to`) or 
        (@start_time >= `from` and @start_time < `to`) or 
        (@start_time <= `from` and @end_time >= `to`))
```

Comment: this is not an correct answer .. look at `bfavaretto` answer for a good example

Comment: DJ_KRAZE, although the answer by bfavaretto fixes my initial problem, neither of these fix the problem described in my edit.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Isn't this a way to fix it (the initial issue) with a single query? My answer is based on the OP's two-query approach.

Comment: his answer will not work in certain scenarios.. suppose say 'from' is  '2013-01-16' and 'to' is '2013-01-23'. And the available dates people want to check is between'2013-01-18' and 2013-01-20'

Comment: @bfavaretto your answer is correct look at whom the comment was targeted it was the answer provide by ajp.. look at what I wrote againg please.. :)

Comment: @DJKRAZE I know your comment was directed to ajp, I'm just not sure his answer is wrong.

Comment: i believe we should have a single query and if we have two queries, we cannot check for the scenrio mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: if he changes the answer to meet the field names of the OP's example then yes it might be correct.. that's all I am saying.. the OP seems to be a bit confused on what's hes doing so I think the example as an answer should match the OP's field names does this make sense..?

Comment: @ajp You have to escape the column names with backticks, since both `from` and `to` are reserved words. Also, although I prefer a single query solution, I don't see why the other one wouldn't work: if any of the two queries find anything, it means the dates are already taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is:

```
select *
from anqehxy1kxmeowpcoqjj 
where @end_time >= `to` and @start_time <= `from`
```

This is an example of an overlapping intervals problem.  Two intervals overlap when one starts on or before the second ends and ends on or after the first starts.

Depending on whether the end date is inclusive, you may need `<` and `>` rather than `<=` and `>='.